# QgsRectangle do not completely draw a rectangle

Tags: qgis, python, qgsrectangle

I create a plugin composed by his own canvas (as widget) and in this canvas the user select a rectangle (for the study zone). I used the RectangleMapTool class.
However, when I draw the rectangle, it is not completed as in the figure.

[image]

```
class RectangleMapTool(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, self.canvas)
        self.rubberBand = QgsRubberBand(self.canvas, True)
        self.rubberBand.setColor(Qt.red)
        self.rubberBand.setWidth(1)
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.startPoint = self.endPoint = None
        self.isEmittingPoint = False
        self.rubberBand.reset(True)

    def canvasPressEvent(self, e):
        self.startPoint = self.toMapCoordinates(e.pos())
        self.endPoint = self.startPoint
        self.isEmittingPoint = True
        self.showRect(self.startPoint, self.endPoint)

    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, e):
        self.isEmittingPoint = False
        r = self.rectangle()
        if r is not None:
          print("Rectangle:", r.xMinimum(),
                r.yMinimum(), r.xMaximum(), r.yMaximum()
               )

    def canvasMoveEvent(self, e):
        if not self.isEmittingPoint:
          return

        self.endPoint = self.toMapCoordinates(e.pos())
        self.showRect(self.startPoint, self.endPoint)

    def showRect(self, startPoint, endPoint):
        self.rubberBand.reset()
        if startPoint.x() == endPoint.x() or startPoint.y() == endPoint.y():
          return

        point1 = QgsPointXY(startPoint.x(), startPoint.y())
        point2 = QgsPointXY(startPoint.x(), endPoint.y())
        point3 = QgsPointXY(endPoint.x(), endPoint.y())
        point4 = QgsPointXY(endPoint.x(), startPoint.y())

        self.rubberBand.addPoint(point1, False)
        self.rubberBand.addPoint(point2, False)
        self.rubberBand.addPoint(point3, False)
        self.rubberBand.addPoint(point4, True)    # true to update canvas
        self.rubberBand.show()

    def rectangle(self):
        if self.startPoint is None or self.endPoint is None:
          return None
        elif (self.startPoint.x() == self.endPoint.x() or \
              self.startPoint.y() == self.endPoint.y()):
          return None

          return QgsRectangle(self.startPoint, self.endPoint)

    def deactivate(self):
        QgsMapTool.deactivate(self)
        self.deactivated.emit()
```

Code where I instantiate the class RectangleToolMap:

```py
canvas = self.dlg.widget
tool = RectangleMapTool(canvas)
tool.rectangle()
canvas.setMapTool(tool)
r = tool.rectangle()
```

Comment: add a `point5 = point1` and after `self.rubberBand.addPoint(point4, False)` and `self.rubberBand.addPoint(point5, True)`

Comment: Perfected it works!!!! Now is it possible to extract the coordinates of the rectangle or even to export as shapefile?

Comment: Yes it is, but you can access to the `startPoint` or `endPoint` or directly with the method `rectangle`.

Comment: Ok, I understand that in rectangle function it returns the QgsRectangle with self.startPoint and Self.EndPoint but I do not now where I can ask for that, in which part of the code.

Comment: The problem is that you give only the class code and not your code part where you instantiate this one.

Comment: I add some part of the code where I instantiate the class.

Comment: And now, you can create your geometry with `QgsRectangle(tool.startPoint, tool.endPoint)`.

Comment: It gives me this error: "    rectangle = QgsRectangle(tool.startPoint, tool.endPoint)
TypeError: QgsRectangle(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: too many arguments
  overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
  overload 3: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
  overload 4: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
  overload 5: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'"

Comment: Yes, you have to draw a rectangle before call this one. You can check by accessing to the attribute `tool.startPoint`, if it's `None`, there is no rectangle drawn.

Comment: Ok I understand. I put the code after clicking on Ok button and it works!! However I must find a way to obtain the values in the moment that I finish the drawing. I will find. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Look at the `pyqtSignal`, an exemple here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36435321, in the signal, send a `QgsRectangle`. Add the `emit` after `self.rubberBand.show()`.

Comment: @J.Monticolo I did not understand how to do it in my code. In the example a class was created "Example", then they used int and str. I am having difficulty to do the same in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working code with your class emitting a `rect_created` signal, connected to the little function `foo` that prints the <kbd>QgsRectangle</kbd> created :

```py
class RectangleMapTool(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):
    rect_created = pyqtSignal(QgsRectangle)
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, self.canvas)
        self.rubberBand = QgsRubberBand(self.canvas, True)
        self.rubberBand.setColor(Qt.red)
        self.rubberBand.setWidth(1)
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.startPoint = self.endPoint = None
        self.isEmittingPoint = False
        self.rubberBand.reset(True)

    def canvasPressEvent(self, e):
        self.startPoint = self.toMapCoordinates(e.pos())
        self.endPoint = self.startPoint
        self.isEmittingPoint = True
        self.showRect(self.startPoint, self.endPoint)

    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, e):
        self.isEmittingPoint = False
        r = self.rectangle()
        if r is not None:
            self.rect_created.emit(r)

    def canvasMoveEvent(self, e):
        if not self.isEmittingPoint:
            return

        self.endPoint = self.toMapCoordinates(e.pos())
        self.showRect(self.startPoint, self.endPoint)

    def showRect(self, startPoint, endPoint):
        self.rubberBand.reset()
        if startPoint.x() == endPoint.x() or startPoint.y() == endPoint.y():
            return

        point1 = QgsPointXY(startPoint.x(), startPoint.y())
        point2 = QgsPointXY(startPoint.x(), endPoint.y())
        point3 = QgsPointXY(endPoint.x(), endPoint.y())
        point4 = QgsPointXY(endPoint.x(), startPoint.y())
        point5 = point1

        self.rubberBand.addPoint(point1, False)
        self.rubberBand.addPoint(point2, False)
        self.rubberBand.addPoint(point3, False)
        self.rubberBand.addPoint(point4, False)
        self.rubberBand.addPoint(point5, True)
        self.rubberBand.show()

    def rectangle(self):
        if self.startPoint is None or self.endPoint is None:
            return None
        elif (self.startPoint.x() == self.endPoint.x() or \
              self.startPoint.y() == self.endPoint.y()):
            return None

        return QgsRectangle(self.startPoint, self.endPoint)

    def deactivate(self):
        QgsMapTool.deactivate(self)
        self.deactivated.emit()


def foo(rect):
    print(rect)


canvas = self.dlg.widget  # or iface.mapCanvas()
tool = RectangleMapTool(canvas)
tool.rect_created.connect(foo)
canvas.setMapTool(tool)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! However I am not able to call the canvas object. The function foo is outside the class right? Then the four lines are also outside the class and I am calling the canvas that is the widget. However it is not working. I am trying.

Comment: Ok, I try it. No errors! But I draw the rectangle and nothing happens.

Comment: For me, with `canvas = iface.mapCanvas()`, with this code executed from the QGIS console, each time I finished to draw a rectangle with the tool, I've a print line with the `QgsRectangle` in the Python console.

Comment: I am not using the Python console. I am using a script associated to the plugin. maybe it is different. However, I have no errors and before I create the rectangles it emits the signal and None. Then I draw the rectangle and nothing happens.

Comment: Ok, I found the error. When I draw the rectangle the return is "None". That's why is not returning anything. When I create my own widget to visualize the maps, is possible do not have a coordinate system associated?

Comment: But If I click on Ok button of my GUI, is possible to read the coordinates (I have an image confirming that).

Comment: @BárbaraDuarte: but if you don't provide more code / informations, it's difficult to answer. My code works under QGIS, so provide more context.